# Centos 6.9 and Phalcon 2.0.13

Tags: php, build, centos, vagrant, phalcon

I'm trying to build phalcon-2 on centos 6.9. php is 5.3.3, gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)

```
yum install -y httpd php php-mysql php-devel git gcc libtool pcre-devel 
unzip
wget https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/archive/phalcon-v2.0.13.zip
unzip phalcon-v2.0.13.zip
cd cphalcon-phalcon-v2.0.13/build
./install
```

Logs: https://pastebin.com/yMf22YSL

Comment: alright php 5.3.3 isn't supported... need 5.3.21+ but no repo has them anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed php 5.3.33 from sources and it worked.

Comment: Great, but that's far from the best scenario. Using that old PHP binary and old and deprecated Phalcon 2.0.x series is not a wise idea. I do understand you must have done it that way as client runs their stuff on PHP 5.3 and old CentOS... so one word to rule them all: legacy. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The latest docs at time of writing recommend Phalcon-3.3 and state:

PHP >= 5.5

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/installation

Comment: I'm installing phalcon-2.0.0. I also resolved it by using php 5.3.33 from sources